# How to convert []int to [2]int?

Tags: go

I have function that returns [2]int. And I have slice `ages[len(ages)-2:]`. How can I convert this slice to [2]int.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func TwoOldestAges(ages []int) [2]int {
    sort.Ints(ages)
    return ages[len(ages)-2:]
}
```

Comment: "How can I convert this slice to [2]int" You cannot. There is no builtin magic which does this. You have to create an array and populate it from your slice manually.

Comment: This seems to be an http://xyproblem.info, you should explain what you are trying to solve with this because I'm pretty sure that a `[2]int` array is not the solution.

Comment: @Adirio: Top N is a well-known problem. For example, in SQL: [TOP (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql).

Comment: @peterSO And where exactly did you see the OP asking for Top N? He asks to transform a `[]int` (slice) into a `[2]int` (array). If he explains the problem (that may be a Top N problem as he is sorting and getting the first two in his code) instead of asking a way to transform a slice into an array we can provide a well-suited answer, as most likely arrays are not the way to go (slices use arrays in the background but directly interacting with arrays is usually avoided as they are a low level primitive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like the below;

```
func TwoOldestAges(ages []int) (oldest [2]int) {
    sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(sort.IntSlice(ages)))
    copy(oldest[:], ages)
    return
}
```

Working example [here](https://goplay.space/#oF0LwCItvAv)

I've added a name to the return argument, that way you don't have to specify what array size you are making in the function. Since the array is bounded to a maximum size of 2 copy will just put the first two results into the array. Therefore we sort your ages (which sorts it ascending) and then reverse it so that the two highest results are the first two keys.

Now if you wanted you can update the size of the array to return without having to update anything inside the method.

**Edit:**
I should probably also mention this protects you from panicing from out of bound indexes as well. For example if you only passed through a slice with a length/capacity of **1** if you relied on `ages[:-2]` you would most likely hit an out of bounds panic:

> panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range [:2] with capacity 1

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to go, I guess you can create a fixed array size of 2, then copy the first two values of the slice into the array

```
s := []int{1, 2, 3} 
var twoElements [2]int
//copy the first two values of slice into the entirety of the array
copy(twoElements[:],s[:2]) //copy returns an int of the elements copied
```

From [go doc](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy):

> The copy built-in function copies elements from a source slice into a
>   destination slice. (As a special case, it also will copy bytes from a
>   string to a slice of bytes.) The source and destination may overlap.
>   Copy returns the number of elements copied, which will be the minimum
>   of len(src) and len(dst).

Good read explaining the go built in copy function with few examples [here](https://yourbasic.org/golang/copy-explained/)

Comment: Be careful with this, you will cause a panic if you pass through `s := []int{1}`

Comment: Yeah, he can wrap up the copy function with an if statement testing the length of the slice of against a constant representing the array size.

Answer (score 1):

Go is designed to encourage efficient code. Your algorithm, because of the sort, is O(n log n). A better algorithm would be O(n).

For example, O(n),

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func TwoOldestAges(ages []int) [2]int {
    var old [2]int
    for _, age := range ages {
        if old[0] < age {
            old[1] = old[0]
            old[0] = age
        } else if old[1] < age {
            old[1] = age
        }
    }
    return old
}

func main() {
    ages := []int{1, 99, 42, 7, 66, 77}
    fmt.Println(ages)
    oldest := TwoOldestAges(ages)
    fmt.Println(oldest)
    ages = []int{1, 77, 42, 7, 66, 99}
    fmt.Println(ages)
    oldest = TwoOldestAges(ages)
    fmt.Println(oldest)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/rq4SMS3MRqY

Output:

```
[1 99 42 7 66 77]
[99 77]
[1 77 42 7 66 99]
[99 77]
```